# Best way to send a notification after an RSS feed updates

Tags: rss, feed, atom-feed, itunes-api

I am trying to make a podcast app that uses the [itunes api](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/). I want it to send the client a notification once there is a new episode of a podcast that they are listening to. I am wondering if there is any specific protocol for this or if there is any specific way this is usually done.

All the ways I can think of are very expensive or cannot be done immediately when a new episode is released.

Comment: Have you tried using WebSub (formerly PubSubHubbub) for notifications: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSub

Comment: Thanks! I will look into that.